# Вызов функции после изменения переменной

Tags: c#

Есть булева переменная ready, равная `false`:

```
static bool ready = false;
```

После выполнения какого-то кода, например, в фоновом потоке, переменная станет равной `true`, а другой поток, после изменения этой переменной, должен начать выполнение своего кода. Притом нужно учесть, что точного времени изменения переменной определить нельзя. Конечно, можно воспользоваться следующей конструкцией:

```
while(true) {
if(ready) { ... }
}
```

Но это далеко не самое лучшее решение. 
Есть ли какие-нибудь другие варианты решения этой проблемы?

Comment: Не использовать переменную а использовать специально предназначенное средство: `ManualResetEvent/AutoResetEvent`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот набросал пример с имитацией того, как можно подождать работу одного экземпляра класса другим экземляром, работа которых запущена в разных потоках.

[ManualResetEventSlim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.manualreseteventslim.aspx)
Но чтобы лучше понять тему работы с многопоточностью лучше почитать об этом в книге. Например, в книге: `CLR via C# - Программирование на платформе Microsoft.NET Framework 4.5 на языке C#. 4-е издание` можно прочитать `Часть V. Многопоточность`.

**Worker.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Worker : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly ManualResetEventSlim _endOfWorkEvent;
        private readonly Worker _worker;
        private readonly string _name;

        public Worker(string name)
            : this(name, null)
        {
        }

        public Worker(string name, Worker worker)
        {
            _endOfWorkEvent = new ManualResetEventSlim();
            _worker = worker;
            _name = name;
        }

        private void DoWorkInternal()
        {
            _endOfWorkEvent.Reset();
            Console.WriteLine(_name + ". Работа начата");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.WriteLine(_name + ". Работа закончена");
            _endOfWorkEvent.Set();
        }

        public void DoWork()
        {
            if (_worker != null)
            {
                _worker.Wait();
            }

            DoWorkInternal();
        }

        public void Wait()
        {
            _endOfWorkEvent.Wait();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (_endOfWorkEvent != null)
            {
                _endOfWorkEvent.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (Worker worker1 = new Worker("Worker1"))
            using (Worker worker2 = new Worker("Worker2", worker1))
            {
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((unused) =>
                {
                    worker1.DoWork();
                });

                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((unused) =>
                {
                    worker2.DoWork();
                });

                worker2.Wait();
                worker1.Wait();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Конец работы программы");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```